# Webform component: Loses value after validation

Tags: webforms, forms

I have a webform component. When submitting (without filling in required fields), I get error messages, but the value of that component disappears. How should the value be retained?

Comment: What happens when you disable Javascript in your browser?  It is possible that there is some JS running that nukes forms upon page load.